# ion Where can I find a good list of Active Directory ldap attributes?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

To be clear, I'm looking for the node data, and NOT the keys in Active Directory's ldap tree node.

To be specific I suppose I'm looking for the official Microsoft documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the link to the AD Schema Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675085(v=vs.85).aspx